# Run an Executable Program File in Multiple Subdirectories Using Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, command

I have a main directory with 361 subdirectories. Within the each subdirectory, there is a  parameter file and one executable program file. The executable file is coded to look for the parameter file in the directory where the executable is located. (The same executable file is in all subdirectories. The parameter files all have the same file name in all subdirectories)

Instead of  executing the program file individually, is there a cshell command for terminal to run them all at once?

Comment: _Thus, the same executable program file is in all subdirectories_. Why? This has no sense.

Comment: Because the executable is coded to find the parameter file in the directory where the executable file is located. So, the executable and the parameter file needs to be in the same directory.

Comment: You are receiving Bash answers because you used the [tag:bash] tag, but in the text, you are saying you use [tag:csh].  Which is it?  They are incompatible; a Bash script will not work in the C shell, and vice versa (except for very trivial scripts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

If your Linux is so old it doesn't have `-execdir`, you could try this:

```
find $(pwd) -name YourProgram -exec dirname {} \; | while read d; do cd "$d" && pwd; done
```

If that correctly prints the names of the directories where your program needs to be run, just remove the `pwd` and replace with whatever you want done in tha directory - presumably something like this:

```
find $(pwd) -name YourProgram -exec dirname {} \; | while read d; do cd "$d" && ./YourPrgram; done
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Like this maybe:

```
find . -type f -name YourProgramName -execdir ./YourProgramName YourParameterFile \;
```

But backup first and check it looks right before using.

The `-execdir` causes `find` to change to the directory it has found before running the commands there.

If your command is more complicated, you can do this:

```
 find . -type f -name YourProgramName -execdir sh -c "command1; command2; command3" \;
```

Check it does what you want like this:

```
 find . -type f -name YourProgramName -execdir pwd \;
```

Comment: Updated, please have another look.

Comment: Would it make a different if I use ./{} instead of "YourProgramName" Also, if the executable file is coded to find the parameter file, do I need to include the parameter file in the command?

Comment: I would put the program name as it is clearer to anyone maintaining the code, but your suggestion should work too. If the executable knows how to find the parameters, then it will work fine without telling the executable where they are.

Comment: I tried the code out, but the terminal responded: invalid predicate `-execdir'. I looked it up, and one forum said that it could be because I am running an old version of Linux. Is there any other code that would work?

Comment: I have added a different method of achieving the same thing - please have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Suppose you have in each folder a file named `params_file` and an executable named `exec_file`, then:

```
for dir in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d` ; do 
    cd $dir
    cat params_file | xargs ./exec_file
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: It's possible that I understood wrong. I assumed that the parameters for the executable are stored in the file. Anyway, Mark Setchell's answer is way better.

Comment: Tudor Berariu, the parameters file and the executable file are two separate files that are stored within each subdirectory. Each parameter file is also unique, although it has the same name in all subdirectories.

Comment: If you need to send the name of the "parameters file" as an argument for the executable, then, as Mark Setchell wrote, use `./exec_file params_file`. If you need to pass the contents of the "parameters file" as arguments then you may want this `cat params_file | xargs ./exec_file`. But use the `find` with `-execdir`, as it's more concise.

Comment: You may want to use the `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` as options for the `find` command if the there exist subdirectories nested under those on level 1.

Comment: Maybe this would clarify things... In each subdirectory, I have two files: an executable file and a parameter file. Normally, I just click the executable file, which reads the parameter file in the same subdirectory. It then produces several output files.